# Camunda multiple bpmn tasks per view in a web page/form

Tags: frontend, bpmn, camunda

I am working on a rather simple (imaginary) BMPN sketch/demo building on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgJQ8nPzEMQ).

I have built a frontend using a Javascript library of my liking, It successfully gets data and posts data to the camunda engine (hurray!). Now I want to build further complexity:

**In my case the apply for loan task needs to be split into the following 3:**

**1.** The user inputs SSN.

(The next task is decided upon whether the person is a new customer or not, 2 or 3.)

**2.** Provide personal address information -> Select Loan type.

**3.** Select loan type.
(if already a customer the address information is provided by a backend system and prefilled)

**Default it appears that all tasks implies a separate view.**
I want to limit the amount of 'pages' of my forms.
Infact I only want one page (see ascii below).

Is there any example or best practise on how to build a standalone form for Camunda/BPMN that contains multiple tasks?

```
SSN:     -------    

Address information:
 Name:    -------   
 Address: -------   
 City:    -------

Loan type:
         (x) A
         ( ) B
         ( ) C
```

**Problems occur:**

1.
- The user inputs SSN.
- camunda moves to task -> Provide personal address information
- The user returns to the SSN field since they made a misstake.
- Camunda must roll back the process to the previous task, 1 step?

2.
- The user inputs SSN.
- camunda moves to task -> Provide personal address information.
- The user enters loan type A.
- The user returns to the SSN field since they made a misstake.
- Camunda must roll back the process to the correct task, X steps?

Is there a best practice for this use?

from the solutions I can think of:

- Locking parts of the form: **BUT!** It feels rather strange to lock some of the fields depending on what task the user is in.
- Multiple pages (standard camunda way). **BUT!** I really want to have all the inputs on the same page!
- The user posts to multiple tasks at the same time. **BUT!** This breaks the usage of bpmn as a view point completely.